# T-SQL Conditional ORDER BY A, B if A is not NULL ELSE B

Tags: t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a hard time achieving the desired results mentioned in the title and described below and unfortunately I couldn't find the solution to this exact issue on Google.

The problem is as follows:
I have two columns A and B in varchar type, the A column could have null values.
I want to print rows ordered by A then B if A is not null, otherwise, ordered simply by B.

The following image illustrates the result I'm getting with these 3 attempts:

Attempt 1: ORDER BY A, B

Attempt 2: ORDER BY CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN B ELSE A END

Attempt 3: ORDER BY COALESCE(A, B), B

They show all rows with A null first then the rows with A not null

[The order I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD6Sd.jpg)

This next image shows the order I want to have:

[The order I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsOoO.jpg)

Your help is highly appreciated to achieve that.

Best regards.

Comment: My attempts:
1st: ORDER BY A, B, will show all rows with A null then the rows with A not null
2nd: ORDER BY CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN B ELSE A END
Both failed, I'm still searching on the net for solutions, thanks for commenting.

Comment: I recommend taking a tour of the site and learning how to ask a good question.  I'm out for now.

Comment: Thanks for the support, this was my first question on this website.

Comment: I'm willing to give your question another shot, provided that you show us the _exact_ output/logic you need.  Your question _still_ shows the original ordering, which my now deleted answer provided.

Comment: I've just edited my question, sorry I didn't know how to put images directly into the post. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(A,'')+COALESCE(B,'')
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try it as soon as I get back to work.

Comment: I have recreated the data from work and this did the job perfectly! thank you very much for your help :)
I was going to stop trying to do it with ORDER BY and just create a temporary column, concatenate A and B values (and add blanks to fill A values to adjust to column A size) then order by that column but this make it a lot easier, thanks again.

Comment: How will this correctly order `'NO', 'T'` and `'N', 'OT'`? Given the small sample data set it isn't clear whether this would be an issue.

Comment: Good point HABO, very unlikely to happen with the data I'm working on (companies register names and trade names, with trade names possibly absent in some cases), if it happens the impact on the report will be insignificant.
However, I have always thought that ORDERBY add an explicit sort by the primary key at the end (since it's always unique), Am I wrong?

Comment: @ZineddineB. Without an explicit `order by` there is no order. Order among matching values is undefined and may change from time to time, e.g. an update to the database engine may cause the query optimizer to do something a little different. So could a change in index statistics. The primary key. if any, is not implicitly included in ordering. (There may be many primary keys when a query joins multiple tables.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on data you provided, try something like that:

```
create table #asd
(
    ID int,
    A varchar(10),
    B varchar(10)
)

insert into #asd
values
(1,'AB','BD'),
(2,'AA','BC'),
(3,null,'AA'),
(4,null,'BA'),
(5,'BA','BE')


select *
from #asd temp
order by
    case 
        when temp.A is not null 
            then temp.A
        else temp.B 
        end,
    temp.B
```

Regards

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try it as soon as I get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
order by Coalesce( A, B ),
  case when A is NULL then NULL else B end
```

That will order by `A` or, if `A` is NULL, `B` and then order by `B` if `A` is not NULL.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try it as soon as I get back to work.